# Editing xml content in java and passing it as string, using node preferably

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I've a xml document, which will be used as a template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:AccountEnabled>true</d:AccountEnabled><d:DisplayName>SampleAppTestj5</d:DisplayName><d:MailNickname>saTestj5</d:MailNickname><d:Password>Qwerty1234</d:Password><d:UserPrincipalName>saTestj5@identropy.us</d:UserPrincipalName></m:properties></content></entry>
```

I'm calling it in java using this code where payLoadXML.xml has the above content.

```
"InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/payLoadXML.xml");"
```

Now I'm trying to edit the tag values for example changing the  from "saTestj5" to "saTestj6" and then converting this entire xml and storing it in xml. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this? I was told this can be done by using "Node" is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = null;
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/payLoadXML.xml");
        doc = docBuilder.parse(is);

        Node staff = doc.getElementsByTagName("m:properties").item(0);

        Text givenNameValue = doc.createTextNode("abc");
        Element givenName = doc.createElement("d:GivenName");
        givenName.appendChild(givenNameValue);
       staff.appendChild(givenName);
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = null;
        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jaxb or sax parsers convert into object by using getter method and change the object and convert back to xml

try [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-jdom/)